# Deciding whether to save to devDependencies or dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm building a react/express app and want to make sure I'm setting up my package.json so that dev packages go under `devDependencies`, and production packages go under `dependencies`.

When downloading a new npm package, what's the quickest way to find out whether I can save it using `--save` or using `--save-dev`? For example, here is my current package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "eslint": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "pm2": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
```

I had a hard time looking up which section each package should go on. I tried looking it up for each individual dependency but never got a really decisive answer so I don't know if I did so optimally.

What's the best way when downloading an npm package to find whether I can save it using `--save-dev`?

Answer (score 10):

Generally, `dependencies (--save)` are for packages that are referenced by your **application** code: code that runs when someone uses your app. `devDependencies (--save-dev)` are for packages used by the **developers** of your app: compilation/build tooling and testing.

There is no strict restriction in npm or node that says package `x` must go into `dependencies` or `devDependencies`. You could install `webpack` in either but if we follow the logic above, the most appropriate section for it is `devDependencies`.

When you publish your package to npm, a user doing an `npm install` for your package can choose to install, along with your package's code, `dependencies` (the usual), `devDependencies`, or both. If they're not going to be modifying code in your package, they won't need anything from `devDependencies`. This is one reason to keep the two sections cleanly separated.

Comment: Ok, but if I don't know a package super well and am not sure whether I should download it to devDependencies or regular, what's the best way for me to find out? You I just go to its npm page and see?

Comment: Yes. You can move packages between `dependencies` and `devDependencies` at any point by editing `package.json` so it's not a big deal if things get installed in the wrong place the first time.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, which is, how can I know if a particular package is needed at runtime in PRODUCTION (where I won't have devDependencies available).

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do. I'm curious to know if there is a better way:

Look up your package on the npmjs.com site and see how they recommend installing it.

If they recommend installing it with `--save` (or simple without any `--save` option), it belongs in `dependencies`.

If they recommend installing it with `--save-dev` (or `--dev` or `-D`), it usually belongs in `devDependencies`.

E.g.:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/runtime

  - `npm install --save @babel/runtime`
  - put it into `dependencies`
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core

  - `npm install --save-dev @babel/core`
  - put it into `devDependencies`

Exceptions:

I've noticed that this method is not always reliable. E.g. `resize-observer-polyfill` which recommends installing it with `--save-dev` but the project I'm working on uses it in production. Then again, if you're using webpack, it might bundle it in for you anyway :).